# Error while kartoza/geoserver:2.24.0 compose file

Tags: geoserver, docker

I have many errors preventing GeoServer from starting. The data directory is clean and I got the errors.
Here is my compose file

```
version: '3.9'
name: uals_gs

services:
  masterGs:
    image: kartoza/geoserver:2.24.0
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
        - "8091:8080"
    volumes:
        
        - "d:\\docker\\geoserver\\data_dir:/opt/geoserver/data_dir"
        - "d:\\docker\\geoserver\\extrafonts:/opt/fonts"

    environment:
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER=flykoh
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=RTk%2iN2sfE3
        - STABLE_EXTENSIONS=css-plugin,sqlserver-plugin
        - BROKER_URL=tcp://0.0.0.0:61661
        - READONLY=disabled
        - CLUSTER_DURABILITY=false
        - CLUSTERING=True
        - TOGGLE_MASTER=true
        - TOGGLE_SLAVE=true
        - RANDOMSTRING=23bd87cfa327d47e-master
        - INSTANCE_STRING=ac3bcba2fa7d989678a01ef4facc4173010cd8b40d2e5f5a8d18d5f863ca976f-master

    healthcheck:
        test: "curl --fail --silent --write-out 'HTTP CODE : %{http_code}\n' --output /dev/null -u flykoh:'RTk%2iN2sfE3' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/about/version.xml"
        interval: 5m30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3

  nodeN1:
    image: kartoza/geoserver:2.24.0
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
        - "8092:8080"
    volumes:
        
        - "d:\\docker\\geoserver\\data_dir:/opt/geoserver/data_dir"
        - "d:\\docker\\geoserver\\extrafonts:/opt/fonts"

    environment:
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER=flykoh
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=RTk%2iN2sfE3
        - STABLE_EXTENSIONS=css-plugin,sqlserver-plugin
        - BROKER_URL=tcp://masterGs:61661
        - READONLY=disabled
        - CLUSTER_DURABILITY=false
        - CLUSTERING=True
        - TOGGLE_MASTER=true
        - TOGGLE_SLAVE=true
        - EMBEDDED_BROKER=disabled
        - RANDOMSTRING=23bd87cfa327d47e-node1
        - INSTANCE_STRING=ac3bcba2fa7d989678a01ef4facc4173010cd8b40d2e5f5a8d18d5f863ca976f-node1


    depends_on:
        masterGs:
            condition: service_started

    healthcheck:
        test: "curl --fail --silent --write-out 'HTTP CODE : %{http_code}\n' --output /dev/null -u flykoh:'RTk%2iN2sfE3' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/about/version.xml"
        interval: 5m30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3

  nodeN2:
    image: kartoza/geoserver:2.24.0
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
        - "8093:8080"
    volumes:
        
        - "d:\\docker\\geoserver\\data_dir:/opt/geoserver/data_dir"
        - "d:\\docker\\geoserver\\extrafonts:/opt/fonts"

    environment:
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER=flykoh
        - STABLE_EXTENSIONS=css-plugin,sqlserver-plugin
        - BROKER_URL=tcp://masterGs:61661
        - READONLY=disabled
        - CLUSTER_DURABILITY=false
        - CLUSTERING=True
        - TOGGLE_MASTER=true
        - TOGGLE_SLAVE=true
        - EMBEDDED_BROKER=disabled
        - RANDOMSTRING=23bd87cfa327d47e-node2
        - INSTANCE_STRING=ac3bcba2fa7d989678a01ef4facc4173010cd8b40d2e5f5a8d18d5f863ca976f-node2


    depends_on:
        masterGs:
            condition: service_started

    healthcheck:
        test: "curl --fail --silent --write-out 'HTTP CODE : %{http_code}\n' --output /dev/null -u flykoh:'RTk%2iN2sfE3' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/about/version.xml"
        interval: 5m30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3
    

  nodeN3:
    image: kartoza/geoserver:2.24.0
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
        - "8094:8080"
    volumes:
        
        - "d:\\docker\\geoserver\\data_dir:/opt/geoserver/data_dir"
        - "d:\\docker\\geoserver\\extrafonts:/opt/fonts"
    
    environment:
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER=flykoh
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=RTk%2iN2sfE3
        - STABLE_EXTENSIONS=css-plugin,sqlserver-plugin
        - BROKER_URL=tcp://masterGs:61661
        - READONLY=disabled
        - CLUSTER_DURABILITY=false
        - CLUSTERING=True
        - TOGGLE_MASTER=true
        - TOGGLE_SLAVE=true
        - EMBEDDED_BROKER=disabled
        - RANDOMSTRING=23bd87cfa327d47e-node3
        - INSTANCE_STRING=ac3bcba2fa7d989678a01ef4facc4173010cd8b40d2e5f5a8d18d5f863ca976f-node3


    depends_on:
        masterGs:
            condition: service_started

    healthcheck:
        test: "curl --fail --silent --write-out 'HTTP CODE : %{http_code}\n' --output /dev/null -u flykoh:'RTk%2iN2sfE3' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/about/version.xml"
        interval: 5m30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3
```

and here is the log i got

```
2023-11-06 01:44:51  Enabling jms-cluster-plugin for GeoServer 
2023-11-06 01:44:53 [Entrypoint] GENERATED tomcat  PASSWORD:  NYnVatBOUFzOTHHp9N 
2023-11-06 01:44:54 /scripts/entrypoint.sh:57 0: CLUSTER_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/geoserver/data_dir/cluster/instance_23bd87cfa327d47e-master
2023-11-06 01:44:54 /scripts/entrypoint.sh:58 0: MONITOR_AUDIT_PATH=/opt/geoserver/data_dir/monitoring/monitor_23bd87cfa327d47e-master
2023-11-06 01:48:58 /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc is nested in /opt/geoserver/data_dir
2023-11-06 01:48:58 [0.003s][warning][gc,ergo] -XX:NewSize and -XX:MaxNewSize override -XX:NewRatio
2023-11-06 01:44:51 --2023-11-05 22:44:51--  https://download.jar-download.com/cache_jars/org.jdom/jdom2/2.0.6.1/jar_files.zip
2023-11-06 01:44:51 Resolving download.jar-download.com (download.jar-download.com)... 104.21.30.50, 172.67.150.151, 2606:4700:3032::ac43:9697, ...
2023-11-06 01:44:51 Connecting to download.jar-download.com (download.jar-download.com)|104.21.30.50|:443... connected.
2023-11-06 01:44:52 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-11-06 01:44:52 2023-11-05 22:44:52 ERROR 404: Not Found.
2023-11-06 01:44:52 
2023-11-06 01:48:58 NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
2023-11-06 01:49:02 05-Nov-2023 22:49:02.264 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/geoserver]
2023-11-06 01:49:24 05-Nov-2023 22:49:24.244 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2023-11-06 01:49:27 2023-11-05 22:49:27,762 main ERROR RollingFileManager (/opt/geoserver/data_dir/cluster/instance_23bd87cfa327d47e-master/geoserver.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/geoserver/data_dir/cluster/instance_23bd87cfa327d47e-master/geoserver.log (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/geoserver/data_dir/cluster/instance_23bd87cfa327d47e-master/geoserver.log (Permission denied)
2023-11-06 01:49:43 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoServerLoader' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.24.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JMSReadOnlyGeoServerLoader': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'config'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JMSConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/geoserver/data_dir/cluster/instance_23bd87cfa327d47e-master/cluster.properties (Permission denied)
```

Comment: The essential error is perhaps this `cluster.properties (Permission denied)` but I do not know what it means.

Comment: Looks like your jar cache is broken

Comment: Can you try again, there have been various fixes that fixes the permission errors in the logs there. Are you using docker volume or host volume for data directory

Comment: i tried both , last time i tried was version 2.24.0

Answer (score 0):

Use docker volume instead of local path, also add variable `RUN_AS_ROOT=TRUE` to geoserver instances.

Example:

```
version: '3.9'
name: uals_gs

volumes:
  data_dir:
  
services:
  masterGs:
    image: kartoza/geoserver:2.24.0
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
        - "8091:8080"
    volumes:
        - "data_dir:/opt/geoserver/data_dir"
        - "d:\\docker\\geoserver\\extrafonts:/opt/fonts"

    environment:
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER=flykoh
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=RTk%2iN2sfE3
        - STABLE_EXTENSIONS=css-plugin,sqlserver-plugin
        - BROKER_URL=tcp://0.0.0.0:61661
        - READONLY=disabled
        - CLUSTER_DURABILITY=false
        - CLUSTERING=True
        - TOGGLE_MASTER=true
        - TOGGLE_SLAVE=true
        - RANDOMSTRING=23bd87cfa327d47e-master
        - INSTANCE_STRING=ac3bcba2fa7d989678a01ef4facc4173010cd8b40d2e5f5a8d18d5f863ca976f-master
        - RUN_AS_ROOT=TRUE
 
    healthcheck:
        test: "curl --fail --silent --write-out 'HTTP CODE : %{http_code}\n' --output /dev/null -u flykoh:'RTk%2iN2sfE3' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/about/version.xml"
        interval: 5m30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3
     .
     .
     .
```

Comment: With   RUN_AS_ROOT=TRUE it work well.  
Thanks